# Matrix multiplication of a Array Cell of function handle

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

I have built up a cell array of `function_ handles` like below:

```
B = {@(x) x(1)+x(2)^2 
     @(x) x(1)-2*x(2)}
```

Assume `A = [1 2; 3 4]`. I need to perform a matrix multiplication like `A*B` to have a cell array as

```
A*B = {@(x) x(1)+x(2)^2 + 2*(x(1)-2*x(2)) 
       @(x) 3*(x(1)+x(2)^2) + 4*(x(1)-2*(x(2))}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you actually want is the symbolic toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy if you have access to Symbolic Toolbox:

```
C=regexprep(cellfun(@func2str, B, 'uni', 0), '@\(x\)', '');
F=arrayfun(@(d) ['@(x) ', char(d)], sym(A)*sym(C), 'uni', 0);
```

This returns

```
>> F
F = 
    '@(x) 3*x(1) - 4*x(2) + x(2)^2'
    '@(x) 7*x(1) - 8*x(2) + 3*x(2)^2'
```

Note that Symbolic manipulation actually simplies the result.

Comment: Mohsen it was a very clever trick. Thanks for your reply again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way other than:

1. writing your own `class` that supports multplications and/or additions of `function_handles` and `doubles`
2. converting everything to string, manipulating the strings, and convert back to function handle (see the wonderful version Mohsen came up with)
3. Do not actually *create* `A*B` but rather just *evaluate* it (just compute `A*cellfun(@(f)f(y),B)` for some `y`)
4. Manually copy-pasting the expressions
5. ...something else undoubtedly ugly.

Just out of curiosity, could you please explain why you 'need' this operation?

Comment: You know i am going to solve a system of nonlinear equations AB(X) = X. X={x1,x2,...,xn} is a vector of n-dim and B(X) is a vector of the same dim holding in each of its row a nonlinear equation in terms of the {x1,x2,...,xn} and A is a nxn matrix of constant values. The point is that each row of B(X) is formed through the program in a FOR loop. I want to use fsolve to solve the set of equations.

Comment: @user2745742: that doesn't really justify this technique. You are basically solving a linear combination of nonlinear equations. There are better ways to do that (gotta run now, sorry)

Comment: I implemented your solution 5) below :)